# VSCode / tslint does not resolve paths in tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

vscode is somehow not honoring my tsconfig.json (for a couple of weeks now, it has been different. eiter my bad or vscode update...)

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "@foo-animation/*": [
            "src/app/animation/*"
        ],
        ...
```

[image]

Respectively in the Problems tab:

> Cannot find module '@foo-animation/animation-micro' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

✓ **Regular base paths** (like `@angular/core`) **are properly resolved**, just my ‘custom’ ones are the problem...

✓ **Compiling, Building, Running... all works like a charm.** So I believe from an angular/typescript-perspective everything is fine. (Also, my fellow developers using IntelliJ have no issues…) So it seems to boild down to „telling vscode about it“.... :-/

My `tsconfig.json` sits in the root-folder of the project. the only thing is, that I use another `tsconfig.app.json`, which includes above `tsconfig.json`.

[image]

**So is there a way to tell vscode where to look for it's tsconfig.json (to encourage parsing those paths) ?**

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952254) and [this VSCode github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463) might be related, but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense)?

Comment: In my current project, I have set up some paths, but i did it in the tsconfig.app.json. I don't know exactly whats the proper way to do that - but compilung and tslint seem to work for me

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while setting up my repositories recently and I think adding this line to your vscode settings.json should help:

```
"tslint.configFile": "./tslint.json"
```

If your tslint.json is not in the root you should add your own path.

Comment: Found the property, set the property and restarted but no effect. I do have a tslint.json, but that does not contain any `compilerOptions.paths` (should it?). Those paths are (see above ↑) in 'ts**config**.json'

Comment: No, tslint does not need the paths and the tsconfig looks correct. Do other linting rules work in your repository?

Comment: Yes, they do. (right quotes, superficious spaces, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `typeRoots` and `types` compileOptions.

`typeRoots` by itself tells tsc where to find type definitions. [see typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typesRoots)

```
"typeRoots": [
      "dirPath/@angular",
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/electron"
]                     /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
```

Using `types` tells it whether there are specific ones that you would like to be resolved. Any other types will be ignored. [see types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types)

```
    "types": [
      "animation-micro",
      "jquery",
      "node",
      "react",
      "prop-types",
      "." //referencing types belonging to paths specified in typeRoots i.e. 'dirPath/@angular/.' , 'node_modules/@types/.' &  'node_modules/electron/.' - needed to resolve namespaces (dependencies)
],
```

Note: Specifying `typeRoots` and `types` compileOptions will exclude types that are usually included by default, unless explicitly included.

Other helpful alternative, depending on your runtime setup and requirements, could be to use the `rootDirs` compileOption.

`rootDirs` allows you to treat everything almost like an 'Über jar' in java (the idea of everything being available in one place). [see rootDirs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs)

```
"rootDirs": [
      "/ts/", 
      "/js/",
      "src/main/resources/static/ts",
      "src/main/resources/static/js"
 ],/* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
```

Depending on your use case, you may not even need both `tsconfig` files anymore using these.

Also note, using `extends` [overwrites](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) the referenced `tsconfig` settings, so be careful that you haven't accidentally overwritten some of your paths. That could also potentially cause issues.